# Conditional probability two coins?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

In a bag there are 5 ordinary coins(1/2 chance of heads and 1/2 chance of tails) and one special coin(always heads).
A coin is taken out from random and tossed 3 times.Given that the number of head appearing is 3 times, what is the probability that it is the special coin?

If A is the probability of choosing special coin and B is the probability of head appearing 3 times.
I need to find $P(A|B)=P(A \cap B)/P(B)$.
Then $P(A)=1/6$.
$P(B)=(1/6×1/2×1/2×1/2×5)+1/6=13/48$.

But what is $P(A \cap B)$?

Comment: $P(A \cap B) = P(B|A)P(A) = P(A)$ since in this case $P(B|A) = 1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$P(A\cap B)=P(B|A)\times P(A)=1\times \frac{1}{6} = \frac{1}{6}$

PS. Note that you actually computed this number when you calculated your $P(B)$.